# Gmail app HTML signature font-size and line-height issue

Tags: html, css, gmail

I'm trying to create a new HTML signature for our company, but I can't seem to get it work nicely on Gmaill app (Android in my test case). Both font-size and line-height changes. I tried different stuff, even deleted the whole HTML signature and try to make a new one with just a few lines to test, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. I tried so many things, that I just have no clue anymore how to fix. I also tried to search for the problem, but I still can't seem to make it work. Please see attached code.

If anyone can help me into the right direction, that would be great. I also included screenshots to show what I mean regarding the Gmail app. As you can see, also text-size is different.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NrYq.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR9Xy.jpg

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>html signature</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            * {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
            img { border: 0px; }
            a { color: #00002E; text-decoration: none; }
            h1.title { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; }
            span.function { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; color: #00002E; }
            #wrapper { width: 100%; max-width: 470px; }
            #border { border-left: 1px solid #00002E; }
            table.functiondetails { width: 100%; margin-top: 5px; }
            table.functiondetails tr { height: 30px; }
            table.functiondetails tr td { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; color: #00002E; }
            table.functiondetails tr td.icon { width: 10%; }
            table.functiondetails tr td.detail { width: 90%; }


            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                #wrapper { width: 90%; }
                #logoColumn { width: 30%; max-width: 30%; }
                #logoColumn img { width: 100%; }
                #functionColumn { width: 70%; max-width: 70%; }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
                #wrapper{ width: 100%; }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="logoColumn">
                                 logo
                            </td>
                            <td id="border"></td>
                            <td id="functionColumn">
                                <h1 class="title">Name of employee</h1>
                                <span class="function">Function | Company</span>
                                <table class="functiondetails" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon"><img src="https://www.mvhmedia.nl/email/handtekening/icon-phone.jpg" alt="Bel ons" width="13" height="13"></td>
                                        <td class="detail"><a href="tel:+31612345678" target="_blank">+31 (0)6 - 12345678</a><br><a href="tel:+31162123456" target="_blank">+31 (0)162 -123456</a></td>             
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon"><img src="https://www.mvhmedia.nl/email/handtekening/icon-email.jpg" alt="Mail ons" width="13" height="13"></td>
                                        <td class="detail"><a href="mailto:n.vermeer@mvhmedia.nl" target="_blank">email@domain.nl</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon"><img src="https://www.mvhmedia.nl/email/handtekening/icon-location.jpg" alt="Adresgegevens" width="13" height="13"></td>
                                        <td class="detail">Address line 1<br>Address line 2</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon"><img src="https://www.mvhmedia.nl/email/handtekening/icon-arrow.jpg" alt="Website" width="13" height="13"></td>
                                        <td class="detail"><a href="https://www.mvhmedia.nl" target="_blank">domain.nl</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NrYq.jpg
```

Comment: some versions of gmail requires, using inline css rather than internal css. Try inlne css.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem either. Thanks for your comment, though!

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Monitor can tell you a lot of information about what CSS properties are supported by the different email platforms. On there it mentions that font-size and line-height are almost universally supported. But it says that style tags in the head or body are not entirely supported, and there is very low support for linked CSS. So your best bet is to try inline styles.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/line-height/

One downside of only using inline styles however is that you can't use media queries. So you could still leave the media queries in a style tag, but they just won't be used by every platform.

Comment: @ClaudiaMvH Did you try this?

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to solve the problem.